# Questions about style/ organization in Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

This is my first venture into assembly, and I'd love a few pointers regarding organization/ style. This code takes an integer and prints the cube (I'm running it on Windows, via NASM), and while the code works, most of it is cannibalized and rewritten from code samples I found online, so a lot of it is still nonsense to me. What I'd like to know is 1) Am I doing anything particularly stupid here? and 2) Is there any way to make assembly code look even remotely elegant/ neat?

Thanks.

```
global main
extern printf
extern scanf 
;This header makes sure it works on Windows/Linux, got from drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/


%ifdef 
WIN32_TYPE  
%define scanf _scanf    
%define printf _printf
%endif

%ifdef
OBJ_TYPE

section .data
public align=4
class=data
use32
%else
section .data
%endif

prompt   db "Please enter an integer to cube: ", 0
msg
db ` is the cube.\n`, 0
format   db "%i", 0
section .bss
input resb 1000

section .text
exit.

main:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp    
push prompt
call printf     
add esp, 4
push input      
push dword format
call scanf

add esp, 8
mov eax, [input]
mov edx, [input]
imul eax, edx
imul eax, edx
push eax
push dword format
call printf
add esp, 4
push msg

call printf
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
nop
ret
```

Comment: If the code is working then this question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'll move it there right away, sorry!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code.

Answer (score 3):

The usual convention is to indent each instruction a few spaces, with the labels remaining against the left margin so they're obvious.

Some like to tab the operands to a straight column.  I find that's not so helpful.

Readability demands explanatory commments. Substantial, detailed function headers explaining arguments and return values are very important.  Additionally, a common style is to maintain a running commentary in a right-tabbed column explaining the gist of what's going on at the left.  Resist graphic junk: ascii art boxes and the like.  They only obscure the code.

The real readability discipline comes when you start implementing more complex flow of control.  Your best bet is to emulate higher level language constructs `while`, `for`, `if/then/else`, and `do/while'.  Use these in the right column of comments while implementint the code on the left. Adopt a label convention:

```
  cmp ax, bx         ; if x (in ax) < y (in bx)
  jge min_xy_else

min_xy_then:         ; then
    mov cx, ax       ;   min = x
    jmp min_xy_end

min_xy_else:         ; else
    mov cx, bx       ;   min = y

min_xy_end:          ; cx is min
    ...
```

As to your code, it's reasonable.  Not sure why you have a `nop` before the return.